# I cannot run an application using Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I created an ASP.NET Core Web API project using Visual Studio and added my own Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "weatherapplication.dll"]
```

[image]

I am trying to run this application:

```
docker build -t weatherapplication .
docker run -dp 127.0.0.1:4003:80 weatherapplication
```

But a browser shows me "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" when I open an address: http://localhost:4003/weatherforecast

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do your container logs show?

Comment: STATUS Exited (145)

Answer (score 0):

Below are some of the issues that I could think

1. ASP.NET 8 Web API, by default runs on port 8080. Either you can **replace port 80 with 8080** or you can host your app in port 80
2. Currently in dockerfile, weatherapplication.dll is written in small letters, whereas in the project name I see that you have used PascalCase. Can you try updating Entrypoint statement in docker file to `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WeatherApplication.dll"]`. If you have mentioned `<AssemblyName>` in csproj, then make sure to update assembly name in ENTRYPOINT accordingly

If the above points don't help, you can debug further with either of the below options

1. You can check the logs of your container in 'Docker desktop' app.
2. Run the container in an interactive mode and check the logs in terminal. You can use the below command as example to run container in interactive mode

   ```
   docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:4003:8080 weatherapplication
   ```

With both options mentioned above, you should be able to see logs. Ensure that you see logs similar to below and there are no errors.

[image: Container Logs]

Comment: When I execute: "docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:4003:80 weatherapplication" I have an error:
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application 'weatherapplication.dll' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Comment: @AleksanderChelpski Have you mentioned <AssemblyName> in csproj? If not, can you try updating Entrypoint statement in docker file to ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WeatherApplication.dll"] (Currently weatherapplication.dll is written in small letters, whereas in the project name I see that you have used PascalCase). If you have mentioned <AssemblyName> in csproj, then make sure to update assembly name in ENTRYPOINT accordingly

Comment: unfortunatelly still the same problem

Comment: @AleksanderChelpski, in the answer itself I have updated another possible cause